# Old Android loaded into new eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, layout

I used to  use  Android 2.2 API with Eclipse Juno but now i downloaded Eclipse neon.3 and imported my old project from  (`File >> New >> Project >> Android >> Android Project from Existing Code`)

The problem is, I can change to Android 2.2 instead of Android 4.4 (as it is now) file by file and the files work.

Is there a way to change them all at once instead of changing them file by file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the version for layout files preview I'd say no, you cannot change it at once. If you mean the android version for the project - right click on the project -> properties -> android -> select the version you want. Hope this helps.

Comment: I went there and there was 2.2 and 4.4W, the 2.2 was set already and the project was 2.2 already but the Layouts are 4.4 :/

Comment: I removed the Android 4.4W and did what you asked me to do, it worked, thank you!